# application without any network communication actually shows network traffic in Task Manager - how is it possible?

Tags: windows-10, task-manager, resource-monitor

I created an application (in Qt/C++) and when run it, I can see in TaskManager that the process associated with this application exhibits some network communication (0.1 Mbps - while the application running, this number occasionally drops to 0 but then it rises to 0.1 Mbps again). See the picture:

[TaskManager screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3sKb.png)

But I know for sure that this my application does not communicate with the internet. I also checked Windows Resource Monitor and I can see that my application does not send or receive any data over the internet.

So how is that possible that I can see that my application communicates with the internet in the TaskManager?

PS: This seems to happen only on one machine. When I try to run the very same program on another machine (VM), the Task Manager shows no network traffic for the process. So what can be wrong on the one machine?

Comment: Maybe check with more advanced tool, TCPView? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview

Comment: I tried to run TCPView and I do not see the name of my application among the processes in TCPView at all.